# sql server web edition and webservices

Tags: sql-server

I´ve been reading Microsoft SQL Server comparison information and I would like to request help in order to understand some programmability features when comparing standard version with web version. Referring to webservices it says that "Web services (HTTP/SOAP endpoints)" is not supported by SQL Server web edition...

I was wondering if anyone could shed some light on that paragraph, consuming or serving webservices is not supported by the SQL web edition application or it refers to something different. If anyone would like to include as e.g. calls to an exchange rate webservice and store calls on the web SQL server, that option is not allowed as inferred on that paragraph?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It simply means that HTTP / SOAP endpoints are not supported by SQL Server. As the text says.

note "by SQL Server". You can connect to it from a web application, just not using a HTTP endpoint. Now, most likely you have no clue waht a http / soap endpoint is because - the are rarely used at all.

I suggest starting to read http://www.devx.com/dbzone/Article/28525 for an idea - it basically is a way to expose objects from sq lserver via HTTP / SOAP directly, and it is indeed VERY rarely used at all.